# C++ - I´m coding my first program, but I ran into some trouble

Tags: c++

I have started to learn C++ lately and wanted to make my first "game"/program. I have run into some difficulties.

My errors so far are as follows:

1. `(rand()%a)` -> changing "a" doesn´t do anything (for example if the generated number is 2 and "a" is 1 the generated number stays 2).
2. The following code does not work:

   ```
   while(!(b = c)){
       cout << "Enter your guess! \n";
       cin >> c;
       if(c<b){
           cout << "Bigger! \n";
       }
       if(c>b){
           cout << "Smaller! \n";
       }
       d++;
   }
   ```

My complete program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Max. Limit
    int a;
    // Random Number
    int b;
    // Guess
    int c;
    // Tries counter
    int d = 0;

    cout << "Enter highest possible number, setting the max. limit for the program. \n";
    cin >> a;

    srand(time(0));
    b = 0 + (rand()%a);

    if(b =! 1){
        c = 1;
    }
    if(b = 1){
        c = 2;
    }
    while(!(b = c)){
        cout << "Enter your guess! \n";
        cin >> c;

        if(c<b){
            cout << "Bigger! \n";
        }
        if(c>b){
            cout << "Smaller! \n";
        }
        d++;
    }
    if(b=c){
        cout << "Congratulations! You have guessed was right! The number was indeed " << b << " !" << endl;
        cout << "You needed " << d << " tries to find the number! \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in `while(!(b = c)){` the `b = c`  part is an assignment not a comparison.

Comment: So use b==c instead of b = c

Comment: also you have a `b =! c`  which should be   `b != c`

Comment: @mike510a `srand(time(0))` is not `srand(0)`. (Has he edited the question?)

Comment: While this is, in general, not a badly asked question the issues here are very commonly asked and answered in most basic tutorials. I suggest that you spend more time looking for bugs yourself. It is more rewarding to find them and it is part of the learning process in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, the first thing you need to know is (as drescherjm already pointed out), `b = c` is not what you want here. Instead, you want `b == c` for comparison.
Another thing is:

```
  if(b =! 1){
        c = 1;
    }
    if(b = 1){
        c = 2;
    }
```

You can avoid initializing `c` to a different value than `b` by replacing your `while-loop` with a `do-while-loop`. If you then also get rid of `using namespace std;` and use `<random>` instead of `rand()`, rename your short variables (`a`, `b`) to what they are actually doing, you're code becomes clearer and more modern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int max_limit{ 0 };
    int random_number{ 0 };
    int guess{ 0 };
    int number_of_guesses{ 0 };

    std::cout << "Enter highest possible number, setting the max. limit for the program. \n";
    std::cin >> max_limit;


    std::random_device now;
    std::mt19937 engine(now()); //random seed
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> r(0, max_limit); //range

    random_number = r(engine);


    do{
        std::cout << "Enter your guess! \n";
        std::cin >> guess;

        if (guess<random_number){
            std::cout << "Bigger! \n";
        }
        if (guess>random_number){
            std::cout << "Smaller! \n";
        }
        number_of_guesses++;
    } while (random_number != guess); //do the code above until this is false

    std::cout << "Congratulations! Your guess was right! The number was indeed " << random_number << " !" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "You needed " << number_of_guesses << " tries to find the number! \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
Enter highest possible number, setting the max. limit for the program.
100
Enter your guess!
50
Smaller!
Enter your guess!
25
Smaller!
Enter your guess!
10
Bigger!
Enter your guess!
15
Congratulations! Your guess was right! The number was indeed 15 !
You needed 4 tries to find the number!
```

So yeah, that's working.

Comment: Kudos for optimal guessing with binary search.

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` assigns `a` the value of `b`
`a == b`  compares de values of both variables. 
About first problem, check about seed.